# html 3 dependent drop down menus populate by text file

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to create in `html5` - 2 drop down menus and 1 input box then a link created by the users choice of the 3 selections. I am unable to put the link together from user input and selections

html

```
<select id="text1" onchange="setupLink();">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select Your Town</option>
        <option value="witbank">Witbank</option>
        <option value="middelburg">Middelburg</option>
    </select>

    <select id="text2" onchange="setupLink();">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select Your Agency</option>
        <option value="huizemark">Huizemark</option>
        <option value="seef">Seef</option>
    </select>

    Here is a link : <a href="" id=lnk>nothing here yet</a> <br>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUrl() {
        var part1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        var part2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
        }

    function changeText2(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
lnk.href = "http://in"+text1+text2+userInput;
lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
}
 </script>
```

I get this:  http://in[object HTMLSelectElement].com/[object HTMLSelectElement]/test  instead of this:  http://inwitbank.com/huizemark/test

Answer (score 0):

Your html block has no field with id=text-three. Did you leave that out of the question?

Comment: I tried the following code, not working
    <input list="agents">
<datalist id="agents">
  <option value="Andre">
  <option value="Susan">
  <option value="Cliffard">
  <option value="Jane">
  <option value="Mark">
</datalist>